# How to create a Alert Message in phonegap while App is in Background and also when app is closed?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, iso

Now I am developing a time reminder application where I need to display an alert message every hour. The alert must also be displayed when the application is running in background and in offline mode as well.

It should work for both Android and iOS platforms.

Please help me out this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this [Local Notification Plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications). Your code needs to look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load

    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // device APIs are available

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Now safe to use device Plugins
        cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
            id: 1,
            text: 'My first notification',
            every: 'hour',
            firstAt: next_monday,
            data: { key:'value' }
        });
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried it but it not working ? Can you give me the steps

Comment: its completely working. I've been using it for a year now.and notification is the only way you can show something without user interaction.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Did you install it and make sure you're calling it from `deviceready`?

Comment: My device is in "Connection to Device" state only.

Comment: Take another look at my answer, I added an example.